# Swift sort array by 2 parameters

Tags: arrays, swift, cosmicmind

The array contains instance of Entity (Graph library for Core Data):

```
let timCook = Entity(type: "Employees")
timCook["name"] = "Tim Cook"
timCook["company"] = "Apple"
```

the above code won't work, I think the && is not the right way to sort by multiple values...

```
self.storage.sortInPlace ({ ($0["company"] as? String) < ($1["company"] as? String)
                             && ($0["name"] as? String) < ($1["name"] as? String)
                         })
```

thanks

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? How should the array be sorted?

Comment: first by company and then by name: Apple Phil Schiller -> Apple Tim Cook -> Facebook Mark Zac -> Microsoft Nadella and so on

Comment: why -1? I just need to know if it's possible and what is the correct syntax....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, if you want to sort by company first and then by name, you first have to check for equality of the companies. If the companies are the same, you fall back to sorting by name, otherwise, you just return the result of the comparison between the two companies.

```
self.storage.sortInPlace {
    if ($0["company"] as! String) == ($1["company"] as! String)
    {
        return ($0["name"] as! String) < ($1["name"] as! String)
    }
    return $0["company"] as! String) < ($1["company"] as! String)
}
```

or even shorter:

```
self.storage.sortInPlace { (($0["company"] as! String) == ($1["company"] as! String)) ? (($0["name"] as! String) < ($1["name"] as! String)) : ($0["company"] as! String) < ($1["company"] as! String)) }
```

Comment: This works, don't complain about as! because this is not the question we are talking about, and I'm sure they are String (take a look to Graph to learn more)

Comment: @MarcelloCatelli Whatever floats your boat. Don't expect that ignoring good practices will get you hired, though.

Comment: @TimVermeulen I know it's not good, but if you take a look to Graph library you'll see what I mean...

Comment: @MarcelloCatelli You shouldn't let a certain library force you to write ugly code. Create `struct` instances as soon as you get your hands on the data (of course with `as?` instead of `as!`). After you've done that, you can manipulate the data much more easily.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `as!` so much. Actually, don't use it at all. If you're so sure that the value exists, you should have chosen another data type than a dictionary.

```
struct Storage {
    let company: String
    let name: String
}

var storage: [Storage]

// fill storage with objects

storage.sortInPlace {
    if $0.company == $1.company { return $0.name < $1.name }
    return $0.company < $1.company
}
```

Comment: So they are not always Strings. The return type is actually AnyObject and thus you should actually use the as?. The objects in Graph are NoSQL style, meaning that not all instances may have the property value. So using as! is you mentally assuring yourself that the values exist, but the application doesn't enforce that it exists, unless somewhere else you are doing that, which actually creates a coupling. If you want to use the Struct approach, create a wrapper class around an Entity object that handles the optionals and such for you :)